# What's the difference between "Conference" and "Meeting"?

Tags: meaning, business-language, differences

See:The meeting will be held in a conference room at 10:00 am.

Is there any problem if I change the position of these two words in the sentence like "The conference will be held in a meeting room at 10 am"?

Comment: None, really. It depends on what the people who pay for it call it, just like everything else. Check with them first about this.

Comment: Usage Note: *Conference* is generally used for a large, formal meeting with a clear and well-defined agenda. *Meeting* is generic, and is mostly used for smaller informal gatherings. Residents' Associations meet locally; representatives of associations hold a conference at the national level.

Comment: Make sure if the place is called a 'Conference Hall' or a 'Meeting Room' -- it usually depends on the size and the facilities available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no conferences belong in conference rooms. Meetings you can potentially have anywhere.

conference from Latin conferre (bring together)

which is almost the same like meeting

Meeting is more of an encounter.

A conference (a bringing together) implies more effort. Usually a conference also takes longer than a (relatively quick) meeting.

So a meeting room might just be a simple room for a quick meeting. (all meeting rooms these days, at least at my workplace, seem to have conference capable phones in here anyway, so the distinction is blurry)

A conference room might be more sophisticated with video conferencing equipment or dedicated presentation facilities.

You can have a meeting in a conference room, as you can meet in any other room say the kitchen or bathroom.

You could also have a conference in the canteen, or the bathroom even though I don't think that is considered best practice.

So having a conference in a meeting room might not make sense, since the meeting room might be to small and lack the proper equipment. Speaker facilities, video conferencing facilities.

Answer (score 1):

As your question suggests, the two meanings can overlap.  Around here (northeast US), *conference* implies that three or more people or organizations are involved.  (This also matches the meaning of *conference call*, a phone call among three or more people.)  *Meeting* implies that it occurs at a specific time and place.

As one example, *conference* is used to refer to an organized gathering of professionals in a given field, which could have some *meetings* scheduled as part of the overarching *conference*.